# Add named_scopes dynamically in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope, dynamic-finders

Just like dynamic finder methods in rails, is there any way to have dynamic finder methods for associated models?

Consider the following models

```
class User
   attr_accessible :name, :phone_no
   has_many :notes
end

class Note
   belongs_to :user
   attr_acccessible :note
end
```

How can I call a dynamic finder of note attribute from the User object?

Comment: What are your Rails/Ruby versisons?

Comment: Ruby version: 1.8.7
Rails Version: 3.0.4 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes are class methods, so User.scope_name (more on scopes here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). If you want to find a specific note that belongs to that user object, you could define an instance method - something like this:

```
def note_with_content(content_string)
   self.notes.where(:content => "#{content_string}")
end
```

or

```
def last_note
   self.notes.last
end
```

And use it the following way:

```
@user.note_with_content("This is a note")

@user.last_note
```

Comment: Hmm your answer is good, but what if I have to add these instance methods dynamically? Suppose a new attribute is added to Note class dynamically then I want to provide an instance method for that attribute as well. How can I do that dynamically?

Comment: `def note_with_attribute(attribute_name, value)` // `self.notes.where("#{attribute_name}" => "#{value}")`// `end`

Comment: ^^^ You could always pass in the name of the attribute to search by

Comment: That sounds great... I will try it.